# Output elements of a dataframe with a function (in R environment)

Tags: r

I was asked in a project to create a function that outputs the price of a stock on a user-specified date and writes an error message if the date is not included in the data. That database is named H and the date column in named Date.
I tried to do that code but that doesn't work, that function and structure has a hard time handle date variable. I suspect that my main problem is because the variable of my function is a date because I tried with a numeric variable and it is was good.

```
facebook=function(d) {
  if (d %in%  H$Date) p=H$Price[H$Date==d]
  else p=c("The date provided is not included in the data.")
  print(p)
}
```

Does anyone already work on a function with a date as a variable ? I need some help to go on with my project. thank you

Comment: Hey Nick, welcome to SO! We'll be better able to help you if you can provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue, including sample data (you can create using `dput()` for instance), the function that isn't working, and expected output.

Comment: Hey, effectively I am new. I made a mistake while posting I forgot my code but now is ok. I hope you can see it and will provide me with some help. Thanks

Comment: @NickK, please re-read comment above with link. We need code AND sample data to effectively help. R has a useful function to dump data in ascii format to post in body of question: `dput`. We only need a sample few rows. Redact as necessary.